# Kubernetes 1.6.2 flannel configuration in centos 7

Tags: kubernetes, flanneld

Using kueadm command I have configured 3 nodes Kubernetes cluster.  Unlike earlier version 1.6.2 kubeadm command configures all the Kubernetes process automatically.   For flannel I used this yml file kube-flannel.yml.  my understanding with  Kubernetes is it will create the container and run the process inside the container  but I see flannel process running on node itself but /opt/bin/flannel binary not in my node. How Kubernetes running the flannel?

How Kubernetes handles this? Is there right document explains this concepts?

1. flannel pod running in master node itself.

> ```
>  [root@master01 ~]# kubectl get pods -o wide --namespace=kube-system -l app=flannel
>     NAME                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP               NODE
>     kube-flannel-ds-3694s   2/2       Running   37         3d        192.168.15.101   master01
>     kube-flannel-ds-mbh9b   2/2       Running   10         3d        192.168.15.102   node-01
>     kube-flannel-ds-vlm20   2/2       Running   12         3d        192.168.15.103   node-02
> ```

2. I see flanneld process

   > [root@master01 ~]# ps -fed |grep flan
   >           root      5447  5415  0 May10 ?        00:00:08 /opt/bin/flanneld --ip-masq --kube-subnet-mgr
   >           root      5604  5582  0 May10 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c set -e -x; cp -f /etc/kube-flannel/cni-conf.json /etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conf; while true; do sleep 3600; done
3. but flanneld is not in the master node

   > ```
   > > [root@master01 ~]# ls -ld /opt/bin/flanneld
   > >         ls: cannot access /opt/bin/flanneld: No such file or directory
   > ```

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more reading found the answer flanneld run inside the continerd.

here is the run details.

https://github.com/opencontainers/runc

we can extract the flannel docker images like below.

```
> docker save -o flannel-v0.7.1-amd64.tar 
> quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.7.1-amd64 tar tvf flannel-v0.7.1-amd64.tar
```